# Calculating confidence intervall for quantiles first by hand (than in R)

Tags: r, confidence-interval, quantiles

It would be great if someone can check whether my approach is correct or not. 
Question in short will be, if the error calculation is the correct way.
lets assume i have the following data.

```
data = c(23.7,25.47,25.16,23.08,24.86,27.89,25.9,25.08,25.08,24.16,20.89)
```

Furthermore i want to check if my data follows a normal distribution (for example). I know that there are tests etc. but i will concentrate on constructing the qqplot with confidence lines. I know that there is a method in the car package, but i want to understand the building of these lines. 
So i calculate the percentiles for my sample data as well as for my theoretical distribution (with estimated `mu = 24.6609`and `sigma = 1.6828`. So i end up with these two vectors containing the percentiles.

```
percentileReal =  c(23.08,23.7,24.16,24.86,25.08,25.08,25.16,25.47,25.90)
percentileTheo =  c(22.50,23.24,23.78,24.23,24.66,25.09,25.54,26.08,26.82)
```

Now i want to calculate the confidence intervall for `alpha=0.05` for the theoretical percentiles. If i rembember myself correct, the formula is given by

```
error = z*sigma/sqrt(n),
value = +- error
```

with `n=length(data)` and `z=quantil of the normal distribution for the given p`.

So in order to get the confidence intervall for the 2nd percentile i'll do the following:

```
error = (qnorm(20+alpha/2,mu,sigma)-qnorm(20-alpha/2,mu,sigma))*sigma/sqrt(n)
```

Insert the values:

```
error = (qnorm(0.225,24.6609,1.6828)-qnorm(0.175,24.6609,1.6828)) * 1.6828/sqrt(11)
error = 0.152985
confidenceInterval(for 2nd percentil) = [23.24+0.152985,23.24-0.152985]
confidenceInterval(for 2nd percentil) = [23.0870,23.3929]
```

Finally i have

```
percentileTheoLower = c(...,23.0870,.....)
percentileTheoUpper = c(...,23.3929,.....)
```

same for the rest....

So what do you think, can i go with it?

The result looks like this:

[image: QQPlot]

So as one can see i calculated the confidence intervall for each point. In contrast to the solution provided by the package qualityTools. There is also a line passing the 1st and the 3rd quartil (i draw the abline(0,1) line).What is the sense by using this line?
I suggest you prefer the way in qualityTools,but than how can is get this confidenceinterval which is not calculated for every point?

[image: QQPlot]

So what way do you prefer?

These question was originally posted on SO under(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481117/calculating-confidence-intervall-for-quantiles-first-by-hand-than-in-r). 
On the recommendation of one user i try to get my question answered here.